# Parsing JSON in iOS app

Tags: ios, json

Here is the code i wrote, but doesn't work, says there is a problem with json, that i don't realy understand, need some help...
take the json from that site, and stamp it as NSLog. If possible i also want to know how to output with some object that i want, and change the name of the value...

```
NSData *allCoursesData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                          [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://floating-headland-9839.herokuapp.com/books"]];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *allCourses = [NSJSONSerialization
                            JSONObjectWithData:allCoursesData
                            options:kNilOptions
                            erro:&error];
if( error )
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
else {
    NSMutableArray *books = allCourses[@"books"];
    for ( NSDictionary *theCourse in books )
    {
        //NSLog(@"Id: %@", theCourse[@"id"] );
        NSLog(@"Title: %@", theCourse[@"title"] );
        NSLog(@"Description: %@", theCourse[@"description"] );
        NSLog(@"Price: %@", theCourse[@"price"] );
        NSLog(@"ISBN: %@", theCourse[@"isbn"] );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That URL returns HTML, not JSON. It's a web page. Since it does not contain any JSON, the JSON parser can't make sense of it. You need to find out what the correct URL is.

It looks like the URL you want is `http://floating-headland-9839.herokuapp.com/books.json`, but you should verify that.